# fetching json api in vueJs log the results but renders nothing (I'm new with Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'm new in VueJs, actually coming from react, the problem I'm having is that when i fetch the data with an axios.get the console.log shows a succesfull response. But when I to iterate through the Array with v-for it renders nothing.
It's quite important so it be super appreciated if you can tell me what im doing wrong or you have a suggestion.
heres the code:

```
    <SignUpForm />
    <h1>Countries List</h1 >
    <div v-for="country in countries" :key="country.name" >
        <p>{{country.name}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import SignUpForm from "@/components/SignUpForm.vue";

import axios from 'axios'

export default{
    name: 'SignUpView',
    components:{
      SignUpForm
    }, 
    data(){
      return{
          countries: []
      }    
    },
    async mounted() {
      const {data} = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keeguon/2310008/raw/bdc2ce1c1e3f28f9cab5b4393c7549f38361be4e/countries.json')
      console.info(data)
      this.countries = data
    }
}

</script>
```

You can see that what I'm actuallt doing is the axios.get in the **mounted(){}** f(x), later I = the data to my empty Array declared in data(){}. => So I can iterate trough the json response with a v-for in a div.

Heres the picture so you can see:
[image]

Comment: if you add `{{ countries.length }}` after `Countries List`, does it change?

Comment: actually it throws 1925 wich is a strange number, i dont think there's so much countries. btw... i just tried this endpoint https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users and it work perfectly. kinda strange

Comment: what do you mean by "throws"?

Comment: renders => Countries List 9251

Comment: I wonder if the issue is something to do with the fact that `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keeguon/2310008/raw/bdc2ce1c1e3f28f9cab5b4393c7549f38361be4e/countries.json` is not valid JSON ... `9251` being the length of the string returned

Comment: that could be actually the point! i will search about it, thanks a lot man! its a challenge so you really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Observations **:**

- countries list is a string and `v-for` is work if the input data is an array.
- No. of objects in an array is `243` but this `9251` is a count of characters in a string.
- Also, if we will try to convert that into a JSON object via `JSON.parse()` getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 6`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    countries: []
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      var vm = this;
      axios.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/keeguon/2310008/raw/bdc2ce1c1e3f28f9cab5b4393c7549f38361be4e/countries.json")
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(typeof response.data); <---- string
          console.log(response.data.length); <---- actual objects in an array is 243 but this 9251 is a count of characters in a string. 
          console.log(JSON.parse(response.data)); <---- SyntaxError: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 6
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          alert(error);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="getData">Click to check Api response</button>
</div>
```